# Why isn't my addition in Verilog overflowing?

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, simulation, adder, testbench

I'm testing a basic ALU in Vivado using a testbench.

One of my tests checks that overflow works correctly. The test has the following form:

```
0000 0001 + ffff ffff = 0000 0001
```

But, I'm getting `0000 0000` instead. My `arithmetic` module is defined as follows:

```
module arithmetic(
    input [3:0] aluOp,
    input [31:0] a,
    input [31:0] b,
    output reg [31:0] result
    );
    
    reg [31:0] temp;
    
    always @(*) begin
        case (aluOp)
            4'b0000: result = a + b;
            4'b0010: result = a - b;
            4'b1010: begin
                temp = a-b;
                result = {temp[31], 31'b0};
            end
        endcase
    end
endmodule
```

It works for the other test cases but not for this one. Does anyone know why Verilog isn't overflowing as expected?

Comment: Why do you expect `0000 0001 + ffff ffff` to overflow to `0000 0001` and not `0000 0000`? `0000 0001` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Because your expectations are wrong. 0000 0000 is the correct answer, with an overflow to bit 32.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany So Verilog doesn't automatically handle overflow then?

Comment: It handles the overflow by ignoring it since  you have not defined a wide enough word to hold it (MSB+1). Putting it into the LSB would just be wrong.

Comment: My apologies. I meant wraparound, here's a better question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/680283/how-can-i-make-addition-in-verilog-wraparound?noredirect=1#comment1811307_680283

Comment: I guess the other answers explain that it's 2's complement math (as is normal just about everywhere). But I'll add that the Verilog compiler may well give you a warning that you're assigning a 33 bit result to a 32 bit register.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the `arithmetic` module, not the testbench.
When you add 2 32-bit numbers, the full result requires 33 bits.  Generally, when you add 2 N-bit numbers, the result requires (N+1) bits.

However, you declared `result` as a 32-bit Verilog signal.  When you add 1 and `ffff ffff`, the 32 LSBs are 0, and the 33rd bit (the MSB) is 1.

In your Verilog code, there are ways to handle this.  You could declare `result` as a **33-bit** signal:

```
output reg [32:0] result
```

If you are instead looking for an overflow bit, you could also do something like:

```
output reg [31:0] result

...

reg overflow;

always @(*) begin
    case (aluOp)
        4'b0000: {overflow, result} = a + b;
```