# How can I make addition in Verilog wraparound?

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, simulation, adder, testbench

I'm creating an ALU in Verilog, and I would like overflow to be dealt with by wrapping around to lower values.

For example:

```
0000_0001 + ffff_ffff == 0000_0001
0000_0011 + ffff_ffff == 0000_0011
0000_0012 + ffff_fffe == 0000_0011
```

Is it possible to achieve this in Verilog?

Comment: Are you sure you want `0000_0001 + ffff_ffff` to be `0000_0001` and not `0000_0000` (which is what you'd get in typical  integer arithmetic on a computer)? What result do you want for `ffff_ffff + 0000_0000`?

Comment: @ThePhoton I'm not deadset on it personally, but it does seem to be what the challenge I'm completing wants. Isn't wraparound a fairly common behaviour on computers?

Comment: Wrap-around is typical, but it doesn't give the results you say you want. Your first example would result in 0, not 1, for example. This would be considered "wrap-around". (or to make it more coceptually simple, mod-256 arithmetic).

Comment: What @ThePhoton is talking about is that normally adding one to the highest unsigned integer yields the smallest unsigned integer, i.e. zero. Your question proposes a wrap-around to one, skipping the zero in between (thus actually incrementing by two). Normally, the result of wrap-around is the same as if you did the addition in a wider type and then just trimmed off the excess high-order bits again.

Comment: @TooTea I see your point! I suppose there's an issue with the test vectors I've been given then. Sorry! Thank you for pointing that out. So is wraparound standard behaviour otherwise?

Comment: What you're asking for is what you'd get if you treat treat these values as signed integers with 1's-complement representation. (This is also a hint as to how to implement it in Verilog, but I don't know if you've shared enough to know that this solution will work for all the corner cases you need to have working)

Comment: It would help us to see the wording of the problem you actually need to solve. It's possible that they are, in a roundabout way, actually asking your to implement a 1's complement ALU.

Comment: @ThePhoton I think it's a case of having bad test vectors actually! As you mentioned, what should `0000_0000 + ffff_ffff` be! This is the test vector in question: `0_______00_00_00_01___FF_FF_FF_FF___00_00_00_01`. It's in hexadecimal, the first hex is the Opcode for addition.

Comment: Sounds like [ones compliment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Ones'_complement) to me as well; but you'd need to check the rest of the specification you're working to.  Of course another possibility is error in the test vectors!

Comment: @jonathanjo it's my error. I checked the course notes and realised one of the exercises was setting up the test vectors! So it's my mistake. Should I take this question down?

Comment: @Connor, yes it's better to delete the question rather than leave it here in a form that can't be answered.

Comment: @Connor if your correct test vectors show ordinary 2s complement wraparound, you'll find it extremely easy to do :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verilog arithmetic is defined for *2's complement* numbers. If you want to perform *1's complement* arithmetic, you need to convert the numbers first.

```
module top;
  
  function [31:0] comp  (reg [31:0] in);
    if (in[31]) 
      comp = -(~in);
    else
      comp = in;
  endfunction
  
  
  reg [31:0] A,B;
  initial begin
    A = 32'h0000_0012; B = 32'hffff_fffe;
    $displayh(comp(A) + comp(B));
  end
endmodule
```